# Miss Cathy's Patients

Tags: story

Miss Cathy is a psychologist. However, there's a problem. She has very bad short-term memory loss. Although she has this condition, she doesn't let it get in the way of her work. Every time a patient comes for a visit she quickly writes the patient's information, the way they look, their personality. She is also very organized and keeps her patient records arranged alphabetically.

One day, business was slow. She only had five patients that day and coincidentally all the patients knew each other. When she was going to store the patients' records, she noticed that she forgot something very important. She forgot to write the names of the patients! The only thing she wrote were their appearance and personality.

**File #1**

> Very fashionista.
>   Wore clothes of different colors.
>   Her dress was very blue like the ocean.
>   Wears high boots the color of mustard.
>   Silky gloves the color of the forest and a very loud hair color of red!
>   Quite a fashion disaster though.
>   She had a lot to say.
>   Very talkative but sometimes she just suddenly stops in the middle of talking.

**File #2**

> Ginger
>   Freckles
>   Very pointy nose, rarely see that kind of lady around these parts.
>   Wore a long elegant red dress with a tinge of orange.
>   Really angry at the first girl.
>   Said she is much better than her and much more pretty.
>   But when she asks people who they like better, most of the time she loses.

**File #3**

> Very old man.
>   White hair
>   Wore blue overalls and a white shirt.
>   Age has really played on him.
>   Slow talker.
>   His cellphone rang and he asked me to answer it.
>   Probably not yet used to new technologies.
>   Says that his generation is being overshadowed now with the new generation.

**File #4**

> Seems to be a character.
>   Quite large...
>   Said he has three siblings, one that works on automobiles, one that is a younger version of himself, and one that is working as a lifeguard.
>   He says he is one of the pioneers that made a lot of phone calls easier. I don't get it though.

**File #5**

> Looks like he's been through a lot of adventures
>   Seems like he won't get lost.
>   Took an apple from his backpack and took a bite.
>   Proud of his energy... Surely, I can see that he is quite energetic

Can you help Miss Cathy identify who were her patients for that day?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> These are browsers. The descriptions are of their logos.

The first one is

> Chrome

The second is

> Firefox

The third is

> Internet Explorer (IE and Edge logos are blue and white.) Question assumes Microsoft doesn't have a phone?

The fourth is

> [Opera](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_(web_browser)). "The siblings are Opera Mobile, Opera Mini, and Opera Coast. It came up with Speed Dial browsing, and its symbol is a big O (large character)." –  Illyasviel

The fifth is

> Safari.

Comment: The fourth is Opera. The siblings are Opera Mobile, Opera Mini, and Opera Coast. It came up with Speed Dial browsing, and its symbol is a big O (large character). [Source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_(web_browser))

Comment: i think you're right, edited

Comment: Might I say number three is a horrible hint? Microsoft OWNS Nokia, and thus has it's own line of cell phones on the market. Unless it's mocking Microsoft for not having 'figured out their 'new cellphone' (recent nature of the acquisition).

Comment: Hi @TimCouwelier, actually it doesn't assume that IE/Microsoft doesn't own a phone line. It follows the assumption that according to people that IE has a lot of trouble coping up with new languages/plugins/extensions etc. This connects to him asking for help with new technology.